# MySQL COUNT values fo each column

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to figure out how to count the values in more than one column.
It seem the first COUNT I do gives me the correct results but everything I’ve tried to get the second column count gives the wrong result.
For example, with the following two columns,

```
  
Q2 Q3  
1   1  
1   1  
2   2  
1   1  
1   1  
5   5  
3   5  
5   3  
4   1  
2   2  
3   3  
3   3  
5   5  
3   3  
2   1  
2   1  
3   2  
4   1  
1   1  
1   1  
2   2  
5   5  
3   3  
2   1  
3   3  
1   1  
2   1
```

```
SELECT COUNT(Q2) AS QU2 FROM mytable GROUP BY Q2
QU2 = 7 7 7 2 4
```

gives me the count for Q2. 7 one’s, 7 two’s  and so on...

However, the following gives me an unexpected result.

```
SELECT COUNT(Q2) AS QU2, COUNT(Q3) AS QU3 FROM mytable GROUP BY Q2, Q3

  7 4 3 1 5 1 2 1 3
```

I think its something with the GROUP BY but I don’t know how to get around it to get the needed result.
So I'm tying to get the result of

```
QU2 = 7 7 7 2 4
QU3 = 13 4 6 4
```

Or

```
QU2 QU3
7   13
7   4
7   6 
2   4
4
```

and so on for QU4 QU5 ... I would appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: Exactly how are you expecting the output to look with your single query?

Comment: sorry - why do you want to count them. the result is not ordered so you cant say how many 1 , 2 or 3 are in the column. can you clarify this a little more

Comment: I'm looking to return two new columns QU2 and QU3

Comment: Why are the counts for Q2 = 4 in the same row with the counts for Q3 = 5? Have you thought this through?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The Q2 column has values in it ranging from 1 to 5 so I need QU2 to have the count of each of those values. So, 7 because there are 7 ones. Another 7 because there are 7 two's and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How `GROUP BY` works?

Let's talk about your first query (I added the column `Q2` in the `SELECT` clause to make its output more clear):

```
SELECT Q2, COUNT(*) AS QU2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Q2
```

First, it gets all the rows matching the `WHERE` criteria, if a `WHERE` clause exists. Because your query doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, all the rows from the table are read.

On the next step the rows read on the previous step are grouped by the expression specified in the `GROUP BY` clause (let's assume it contains only one expression, as the query above does). Internally, grouping the rows requires sorting them first.

This is how the data is organized on this step. I added horizontal separators between the rows that go in each group to make everything clear:

```
Q2  Q3  
-------
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
-------
 2   1  
 2   1  
 2   1  
 2   1  
 2   2  
 2   2  
 2   2  
-------
 3   2  
 3   3  
 3   3  
 3   3  
 3   3  
 3   3  
 3   5  
-------
 4   1  
 4   1  
-------
 5   3  
 5   5  
 5   5  
 5   5  
-------
```

On the next step, from each group it **creates** a single row that goes to the generated result set.

The query above clearly returns:

```
Q2  QU2
--------
 1    7
 2    7
 3    7
 4    2
 5    4
```

### What happens when the `GROUP BY` clause contains more than one expression?

Let's take your second query (again, I added some columns to show its behaviour):

```
SELECT Q2, Q3, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Q2, Q3
```

It works similar with the previous query but, because the `GROUP BY` clause contains two expression, each group created for the values of `Q2` is split in sub-groups based on the value of `Q3`. Assuming there is another expression (let' say, `Q4`) in the `GROUP BY` clause, each sub-group created for a pair `(Q2, Q3)` is further divided into sub-groups for all the values of `Q4` and so on.

For your table, the groups and sub-groups are as follows:

```
Q2  Q3  
=======
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
 1   1  
=======
 2   1  
 2   1  
 2   1  
 2   1  
  ---
 2   2  
 2   2  
 2   2  
=======
 3   2  
  ---
 3   3  
 3   3  
 3   3  
 3   3  
 3   3  
  ---
 3   5  
=======
 4   1  
 4   1  
=======
 5   3  
  ---
 5   5  
 5   5  
 5   5  
=======
```

I used double lines to separate the groups and smaller single lines to separate the subgroups inside each group.

The output of this query is:

```
Q2  Q3  cnt
------------
 1   1   7
 2   1   4
 2   2   3
 3   2   1
 3   3   5
 3   5   1
 4   1   2
 5   3   1
 5   5   3
```

### How to get the desired result?

It is not possible to get the result you want using a single query. Even more, the result sets you suggest doesn't make much sense.

You can combine two queries using `UNION` in order to get the data you need **and** additional information that helps you know where those numbers come from:

```
SELECT 'Q2' AS source, Q2 AS q, COUNT(Q2) AS cnt FROM mytable GROUP BY Q2
UNION
SELECT 'Q3' AS source, Q3 AS q, COUNT(Q3) AS cnt FROM mytable GROUP BY Q3
```

The output is:

```
 source  q  cnt
----------------
   Q2    1   7
   Q2    2   7
   Q2    3   7
   Q2    4   2
   Q2    5   4  
   Q3    1  13
   Q3    2   4
   Q3    3   6
   Q3    5   4
```

Pretty clear, isn't it? The first 5 rows come from the query `GROUP BY Q2` and their value in the column `q` tells what was the value of `Q2` for each group (there are `7` occurrences of `1` in column `Q2`, `7` of `2`, `7` of `3`, `2` of `4` and so on). The last 4 rows tell the similar story about `Q3` (`13` rows have `1` in column `Q3` and so on).

#### Remark

There is a difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(Q2)`: `COUNT(*)` counts the rows from the group, `COUNT(Q2)` counts the not-`NULL` values in the column `Q2`. It doesn't care about duplicate, it only ignore the `NULL` values. If you want to count the distinct values then you have to add the `DISTINCT` keyword: `COUNT(DISTINCT Q2)`.

Comment: Very well put. This will work I can do the reset in my PHP code. Thank you

Comment: I just wanted to add because of the way you explained it I understand that even if I got the results I wouldn’t know where they came from without a reference “source”. You’re right it made no sense.
 And the way you laid it out I see one of my attempts at a query (not shown) I didn’t think worked in fact did as shown in your first organized step. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will get you closest to what you want. You can replace the numbers table with any method that generates the numbers 1 to whatever the max value is in Q2 or Q3.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers (num INT)
INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers (num) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)

SELECT
    N.num,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MT.Q2 = N.num THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS QU2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MT.Q3 = N.num THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS QU3
FROM
    dbo.Numbers N
CROSS JOIN dbo.My_Table MT
GROUP BY
    N.num
```

Adding additional columns (for Q4, etc.) just means adding another `SUM(CASE...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to unpivot the data.  In this case, that just means multiple `group by` connected by `union all`:

```
select 'q2' as which, q2, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by q2
union all
select 'q3' as which, q3, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by q3;
```

You can add as many more subqueries as you like.

Note:  this puts the values in separate rows, rather than in separate columns.

Answer (score -1):

I reckon Asaph is on the right track , however I would alter this slightly try `select distinct count(Q2) as QU2, count(Q3) as QU3 from myTable;`

Comment: This is just going to give you 27, 27.

Comment: @Tom H you are right `select count(distinct Q2) as QU2, count(distinct Q3) as QU3 from myTable; is the right way to go`

Comment: @FlyBYNight this query produces `5, 4`.